# What is the semantically correct way to add indexes on elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, semantic-markup

Suppose there are a group of elements on a page and they need to dynamically accessed in JavaScript. What is the semantically correct way to store this data on an object? Is it a class or a data attribute?

```
<li class="question question1"></li>
<li class="question question2"></li>
<li class="question question3"></li>
```

and access the element like:

```
$('.question' + index)
```

OR

```
<li class="question" data-question-index="1"></li>
<li class="question" data-question-index="2"></li>
<li class="question" data-question-index="3"></li>
```

and access the element like:

```
$('[data-question-index=' + index + ']')
```

Comment: Using classname will be be much faster (I mean to access them afterwards). But what is the goal of adding indices ?

Comment: Define “semantically correct”. Such slogans lack defined meaning (semantics), and asking for semantically correct means a call for opinions and debate.

Answer (score 1):

How long is a piece of string?

1. They already have indexes (`$(".question").eq(1)` is the second one, for instance; `$(".question").eq(1).index()` will return `1` if all of the `li`s in the `ul` have the class).
2. Using a `data-*` attribute is perfectly fine if that works for your use case; you do of course have to reorder them if you add/delete.
3. Using a `class` is perfectly fine if that works for your use case (perhaps somewhat unusual); you do of course have to reorder them if you add/delete.
4. Using an `id` is perfectly fine if that works for your use case (and is *really quick* to look up, if that's important); you do of course have to reorder them if you add/delete.

Answer (score -1):

html

```
<li class="question"></li>
<li class="question"></li>
<li class="question"></li>
```

then js looks like

```
$('.question').get(index)
```

[Get Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/get/)